# Android: Request the focus for a boutton instead of the EditText

Tags: android, android-button

I have some edit texts in my Scroll Layout.
On the bottom, I have a button.

Actually, on each opening of the view, the first editText requests the focus automaticaly. I would like that the button gets the focus.

I have try this, but without success:

```
final ScrollView s = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
    s.post(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
             Button button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveProfileEditingButton);
             button.requestFocus();
       }
    });
```

Thank you for your hlep.

Comment: It may not be working because button only exists inside the run statement in your runnable...

Comment: No Drake, nothing changes when i create the button globaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` to your activity in **AndroidManifest.xml** to hide the keyboard (opened due to focus on EditText). Afterwards your other views may receive the focus.

---

**Update**

```
final ScrollView s = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
s.post(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
             EditText editText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
             (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                   .hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);

             Button button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveProfileEditingButton);
             button.setFocusable(true);
             button.requestFocus();
      }
});
```

Comment: does EditText open the soft-keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working but how you checked or what's the sense to set focus on Button. To Check it is working or not use

```
boolean r = btn.requestFocus();
Log.i("Tag", String.valueOf(r));
```

Comment: Thank you @Krishnakant Dalal, the purpose is that: I have 5 edit texts with a button on the bottom. For the 5th edit text, i am opening a new view to choose the country from a list. Then when chooses, come back and fill the 5th edit text automaticaly. At this moment, i would like to request focus for the button and show the bottom of my page, and actually, I am displaying the first focused edit text with the keyboard open...

Comment: And with the text, focused is true for the button

Comment: Its ok you make it so complex if your purpose is resolved it all right. You can accept and upvote the post.